# Jasmine/Protractor time out after bundling/minification

Tags: jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have a e2e spec in Jasmine, executed with Protractor. Everthing worked fine, until I started to bundle my scripts into one. After doing it, Jasmine timeouts on every spec. Basically I see "Waiting for localhost..." and app seems to be waiting for something - it never starts ad I can see AngularJS bindings

> {{}}

all over the page.

My bundled files seems to be ok because when I access application directly (no chromedriver), then I works ok.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

**EDIT**
I tried to play around with files order, including/excluding files and it seems that is has impact on whether e2e tests start or not. For instance, I've excluded, seemingly random file, with a module that decorates $exceptionHandler. And removing this file from the bundle caused the application start to fail, but when I add it once again, it works.

Does order of files / dependencies between modules could be the issue?

Also I've played around with adding/removing scripts with **NO** content eg.

```
<script src="../components/dummy.js"></script>
```

And adding/removing the script fixes/breaks e2e tests.

This is complete console log:

> Using the selenium server at xxxxx
>   A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
>   The last active task was:
>   WebDriver.executeScript()
>
> ```
> at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (c:\UBS\dev\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:302:15)
>
> at webdriver.WebDriver.executeScript (c:\UBS\dev\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:446:15)
>
> at Protractor.get (c:\UBS\dev\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\protractor.js:1222:15)    
>
> at null.<anonymous> (C:\UBS\dev\bx-template-project\src\test\e2e\scenarios.js:8:17)       
>
> at c:\UBS\dev\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14
>
> at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (c:\UBS\dev\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1640:20)
>
> at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (c:\UBS\dev\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1505:8)
>
> at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:261:14)                                                                                                              
> at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
> ```

Comment: Open the developer tools. Maybe you can find a useful error message.

Comment: When I try to open it when chromedriver is launching it, Chrome exits

Comment: Add a browser.debugger() or a browser.sleep(9999999). You cannot have the dev tolls open while protractor is running.

Comment: No luck. browser.debugger does not work. browser.sleep is not usefull, because spec is hanging on the browser.get('url') call

Comment: I encountered protractor trouble that any equations outside "describe" or "it" prevent test to go forward. Maybe the change of specifications.